# Return value from function to Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return a value from a function and not sure how to go about this. The location I want to return it to is a merged cell from "G22:I26" on worksheets(1) and the original function is being done on worksheets(3).

```
Sub CountBlank()
    Dim xxEmpty As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
      LastRow = Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
      xxEmpty = Worksheets(3).CountBlank(Range("CY2:CY" & LastRow))
      Return xxEmpty = Worksheets(1).Cells("G22:I26") 'Syntax Error 

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to return a value from a *function*, why are you using a *sub*?

Comment: Assignment is the other way round: `Worksheets(1).Range("G22:I26").Value = xxEmpty`

Comment: I went to reformat this as a function to give you a quick answer, and I realized that you're also attempting to recursively use / overload the built-in `CountBlank ` function, so that's also going to be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to return a function result**

Basically you return results to a **function** and not to a sub procedure (leave aside direct changes to parameters passed by reference - `ByRef`). `Return` is no valid method to return such function results as in other programming languages, you have to assign a value to the function itself.

Furthermore you have to use the `Worksheetfunction.CountBlank` function (or `Application.CountBlank`), CountBlank itself is no function or method related to a worksheet as you tried by `xxEmpty = Worksheets(3).CountBlank(…)`.

Eventually avoid to *overload* procedures with existing names, so call your function e.g. `getBlanks()`, but not `CountBlank()`.

a) Example call showing the result in VB Editor's immediate window:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print getBlanks(Worksheets(3).Range("CY2:CY" & LastRow)) & " blank rows counted"
End Sub

Function getBlanks(rng As Range) As Long
' Help:
'      Return xxEmpty = Worksheets(1).Cells("G22:I26") 'Syntax Error
     getBlanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng)
End Function
```

If you want to return the function result directly to a cell, you could either just enter the function name choosing a precise range as argument:

```
=getBlanks(CY2:CY4711)
```

or you'd have to modify the function a little bit if you want to count only blanks from say row 2 up to the last entry.